# rtorrent on windows: -bash: wget: command not found

Tags: windows, bash, libtorrent

I installed Cygwin x86 on my Windows 8 Pro x64 on default settings and then I start Cygwin terminal. Then I got "-bash: wget: command not found"

I'm following [this guide](http://rtwi.jmk.hu/wiki/rTorrentOnWindows)

How do I fix this?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Install wget as well through the setup screen of Cygwin although it would risk having updates with other packages. You can also install a native executable manually in a place valid with path like c:\windows\system32. See http://users.ugent.be/~bpuype/wget/.

Comment: Hello, thanks for replying. I done that, but now I got another error."Make" on "installing rTorrent" fails with message, "make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop." What now. Thanks

Comment: @PartogiPane You can ask if there's something you need to clarify or report back how it goes.

Comment: Yes, it says, "make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop." It happened when I typed "make" on "Installing rTorrent" step.

Comment: Perhaps you have to run `./configure`. By the way, why not just use [qbittorrent](http://www.qbittorrent.org/)?

Comment: I have typed "./configure --with-xmlrpc-c". I'm now using BitTorrent 7.8.1. I want to try rTorrent because top seeders on some torrent site use that client. What about qBittorrent? Is it better than BitTorrent 7.8.1?